# Вывод последних или первых записей

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Как составить зпрос к БД MySQL для вывода последних или первых записей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функцию desk или asc. Пример

```
SELECT name, id FROM peoples ORDER BY id DESC
SELECT name, id FROM peoples ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

Используя сортировку и лимитированный вывод.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

вернет первую запись

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

вернет последнюю запись